# Evaluating calculator top output array into correct answer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to get the top readout for a calculator to take a series of numbers and operators("-", "+", "*", and "/") and output the correct result. I can do it for two numbers, eg. (23.45 + 94.35) and then hit the equals button and it does return the correct answer. But then I have to hit the clear button before I can do another calculation. I would like to be able to keep entering new numbers and operators before hitting the equals button and get the correct answer, leaving the equation on the top readout, and the calculated answer in the bottom readout. Any help would be appreciated!! My HTML and JavaScript is included below... My CodePen link is: http://codepen.io/RDaniels34/pen/MKXOKx

```
  html lang="en-US">

  <head>

  <title>RDaniels34 | Calculator</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700|Bitter:400,400italic|Josefin+Sans:400,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <style>
    <!-- #main {
        width: 100px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 3px solid #c3c3c3;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        /* Safari */
        -webkit-flex-flow: row-reverse wrap;
        /* Safari 6.1+ */
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: wrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
      }

      #main div {
        width: 55px;
        height: 50px;
      }  -->
  </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: lightyellow;">
  <header>
    <div class="header-div">
      <h1>Calculator</h1>
      <h3>Made by: RDaniels34</h3>
    </div>
  </header>

  <container class="container">

    <div class="well well-lg" id="numberDisplay">
      <div id="numberDisplay1">0</div>
      <br>
      <div id="numberDisplay2">0</div>
    </div>

    <div id="separator-line"></div>

    <div id="buttonGroup">
      <button type="button" onclick="clrFunction()" id="clr" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">C</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="divideFunction()" id="divideNum" class="divideNum operators btn btn-default btn-sm">/</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="timesFunction()" id="timesNum" class="timesNum btn btn-default btn-sm ">X</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="backspaceFunction()" id="backspace" class="backspace btn btn-default btn-sm fa fa-caret-left" style="font-size:20px"></button>
      <button type="button" onclick="sevenFunction()" id="numbers" class="numbers btn btn-default btn-sm">7</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="eightFunction()" id="numbers" class="numbers btn btn-default btn-sm">8</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="nineFunction()" id="numbers" class="numbers btn btn-default btn-sm">9</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="addFunction()" id="addNum" class="addNum btn btn-default btn-sm">+</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="fourFunction()" id="numbers" class="numbers btn btn-default btn-sm">4</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="fiveFunction()" id="numbers" class="numbers btn btn-default btn-sm">5</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="sixFunction()" id="numbers" class="numbers btn btn-default btn-sm">6</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="subtractFunction()" id="minusNum" class="minusNum btn btn-default btn-sm">-</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="oneFunction()" id="numbers" class="numbers btn btn-default btn-sm">1</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="twoFunction()" id="numbers" class="numbers btn btn-default btn-sm">2</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="threeFunction()" id="numbers" class="numbers btn btn-default btn-sm">3</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="percentFunction()" id="percentNum" class="percentNum btn btn-default btn-sm ">%</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="zeroFunction()" id="numbers" class="numbers btn btn-default btn-sm">0</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="decimalFunction()" id="numbers" class="numbers btn btn-default btn-sm ">.</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="plusminusFunction()" id="plusminus" class="plusminus btn btn-default btn-sm">+/-</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="rd34Function()" id="rd34" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">RD</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="equalsFunction()" id="equals" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">=</button>
    </div>
  </container>


  <div id="footer">
    Copyright © RDaniels34 - 2016
  </div>

  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="scripts/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>


JavaScript

/**************************************************** 
   Mathematical Functions Buttons For Top Readout
*****************************************************/

var topNumber = [];
eval(topNumber.join(''));
///var newAnswer = topNumber; 

function clrFunction() {
  topNumber.splice(0, topNumber.length);
  document.getElementById("numberDisplay1").innerHTML = 0;
}

function divideFunction() {
  topNumber[topNumber.length] = " / ";
  document.getElementById("numberDisplay1").innerHTML = topNumber.join("");
}

function timesFunction() {
  topNumber[topNumber.length] = " X ";
  document.getElementById("numberDisplay1").innerHTML = topNumber.join("");
}

function backspaceFunction() {
  topNumber.splice(topNumber.length - 1, 1);
  document.getElementById("numberDisplay1").innerHTML = topNumber.join("");
  if (topNumber.length == []) {
    document.getElementById("numberDisplay2").innerHTML = "";
  }
}

function subtractFunction() {
  topNumber[topNumber.length] = " - ";
  document.getElementById("numberDisplay1").innerHTML = topNumber.join("");
}

function addFunction() {
  topNumber[topNumber.length] = " + ";
  document.getElementById("numberDisplay1").innerHTML = topNumber.join("");
}

function percentFunction() {
  topNumber[topNumber.length] = "% ";
  document.getElementById("numberDisplay1").innerHTML = topNumber.join("");
}

function rd34Function() {
  document.getElementById("numberDisplay1").innerHTML = "Programming is Fun!";
}

function decimalFunction() {
  topNumber[topNumber.length] = ".";
  document.getElementById("numberDisplay1").innerHTML = topNumber.join("");
}

/********************************************* 
      Upper Display Number Button Functions 
**********************************************/

function oneFunction() {
  topNumber[topNumber.length] = 1;
  document.getElementById("numberDisplay1").innerHTML = topNumber.join("");
}

function twoFunction() {
  topNumber[topNumber.length] = 2;
  document.getElementById("numberDisplay1").innerHTML = topNumber.join("");
}

function threeFunction() {
  topNumber[topNumber.length] = 3;
  document.getElementById("numberDisplay1").innerHTML = topNumber.join("");
}

function fourFunction() {
  topNumber[topNumber.length] = 4;
  document.getElementById("numberDisplay1").innerHTML = topNumber.join("");
}

function fiveFunction() {
  topNumber[topNumber.length] = 5;
  document.getElementById("numberDisplay1").innerHTML = topNumber.join("");
}

function sixFunction() {
  topNumber[topNumber.length] = 6;
  document.getElementById("numberDisplay1").innerHTML = topNumber.join("");
}

function sevenFunction() {
  topNumber[topNumber.length] = 7;
  document.getElementById("numberDisplay1").innerHTML = topNumber.join("");
}

function eightFunction() {
  topNumber[topNumber.length] = 8;
  document.getElementById("numberDisplay1").innerHTML = topNumber.join("");
}

function nineFunction() {
  topNumber[topNumber.length] = 9;
  document.getElementById("numberDisplay1").innerHTML = topNumber.join("");
}

function zeroFunction() {
  topNumber[topNumber.length] = 0;
  document.getElementById("numberDisplay1").innerHTML = topNumber.join("");
}

/**************************************************** 
   Mathematical Function Buttons For Bottom Readout
*****************************************************/

$(document).ready(function() {

  var testNumLength = function(firstNumber) {
    if (firstNumber.length > 9) {
      $("#numberDisplay2").text(firstNumber.substr(firstNumber.length - 9, 9));
      if (firstNumber.length > 15) {
        $("#numberDisplay1").text(firstNumber.substr(firstNumber.length - 15, 15));
        firstNumber = "";
        $("#numberDisplay2").text("Err");
      }
    }
  }
  var topNumber = "";
  //var firstNumber = "";
  var secondNumber = "";
  var answer = "";
  var newAnswer = "";
  var operator = "";

  $("#numberDisplay2").text("0");

  $(".numbers").click(function() {
    topNumber += $(this).text();
    $("#numberDisplay2").text(topNumber);
    testNumLength(topNumber);
  });

  // $(".operators").click(function() {
  //   operator = $(this).text();
  //   secondNumber = firstNumber;
  //   firstNumber = "";
  //   $("#numberDisplay2").text();
  // });

  $(".addNum").click(function() {
    operator = $(this).text();
    secondNumber = topNumber;
    topNumber = "";
    $("#numberDisplay2").text();
  });

  $(".minusNum").click(function() {
    operator = $(this).text();
    secondNumber = topNumber;
    topNumber = "";
    $("#numberDisplay2").text();
    //$("#numberDisplay1").text(newAnswer + operator);
    // answer =  newAnswer - secondNumber;
  });

  $(".divideNum").click(function() {
    operator = $(this).text();
    secondNumber = topNumber;
    topNumber = "";
    $("#numberDisplay2").text();
  });

  $(".timesNum").click(function() {
    operator = $(this).text();
    secondNumber = topNumber;
    topNumber = "";
    $("#numberDisplay2").text();
  });

  $(".percentNum").click(function() {
    if (operator = "-") {
      answer = parseFloat(topNumber) - ((parseFloat(topNumber) * ((parseFloat(secondNumber)) / 100)));
    } else if (operator = "*") {
      answer = parseFloat(topNumber) * (parseFloat(topNumber) * (parseFloat(secondNumber) / 100));
    } else if (operator = "+") {
      answer = parseFloat(topNumber) + (parseFloat(topNumber) * (parseFloat(secondNumber) / 100));
    } else if (operator = "/") {
      answer = (parseFloat(topNumber)) / ((parseFloat(secondNumber) / 100));
    }

    $("#numberDisplay2").text(answer);
  });

  $("#clr").click(function() {
    topNumber = "";
    $("#numberDisplay2").text("0");
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "clr") {
      topNumber = "";
    }
  });

  $("#backspace").click(function() {
    topNumber = topNumber.substring(0, topNumber.length - 1);
    document.getElementById("numberDisplay2").innerHTML = "";
  });

  $("#equals").click(function() {
    if (operator == "+") {
      answer = parseFloat(topNumber) + parseFloat(secondNumber);
    } else if (operator == "-") {
      answer = secondNumber - topNumber;
    } else if (operator == "X") {
      answer = secondNumber * topNumber;
    } else if (operator == "/") {
      answer = secondNumber / topNumber;
    } // else if (operator == "%") {
    //  answer = secondNumber / 100;
    //}

    answer; //newAnswer = 
    //newAnswer = eval(topNumber.join(""));
    $("#numberDisplay2").text(answer.toPrecision(6));
    //$("#numberDisplay2").text(answer.eval(newAnswer));
  });
});
```

Comment: Anyone? Suggestions?